# Is there are way to impute missing values by clustering, regression and stochastic regression

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-cleaning, data, data-imputation

I'd like to know if there are any libraries that allow imputation by **clustering**, **regression** and **stochastic** **regression**. So far, I've done imputation by mean, median and KNN. I'm trying to evaluate the best imputation method for an small dataset (Iris in this case). I had to delibrately create NaN values since Iris set has none.

My code for KNN imputation:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import random
 from fancyimpute import KNN

 data = pd.read_csv("D:/Iris_classification/train.csv")
 mat = data.iloc[:,:4].as_matrix()

 prop = int(mat.size * 0.5) #Set the % of values to be replaced
 i = [random.choice(range(mat.shape[0])) for _ in range(prop)] #Randomly choose indices of 
 j = [random.choice(range(mat.shape[1])) for _ in range(prop)] #the numpy array 

 mat[i,j] = np.NaN #replace values with NaN



 mat_filled = pd.DataFrame(KNN(3).complete(mat)) #converted the array back to df

 data_col = data.drop('species', axis = 1)
 mat_filled.columns = data_col.columns  #added column names that went missing in mat_filled
```

Is there a similar way to impute with the other 3 methods?

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn has an [`impute`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.impute) module that supports many of those imputation methods.

Answer (score 0):

Scikit-learn `KNNImputer` is actually a Clustering-based Imputation method you can use, which imputes missing values using k-Nearest Neighbors.

You can also use `IterativeImputer` to use a regression-based imputation method.